# A Letter: The Archenemy

Tags: riddle, anagram

A week ago, when I was travelling on an airplane to my city London, I found an envelope. The strange thing was that I found my name on it. So, I opened it. It read:

> Hi,
>   Did you miss me?  I hope you are alright.
>   You remember me, right? I am your archenemy.
>   And your closest person. What is he doing? Does he get any patients now?
>   I also hope your elder girlfriend Nerie is fine.
>   I am waiting for you at your home. And yeah, I have the key to the last part of your name.
>
> Yours,

The letter was not signed. Can you guess who he was? Or as a matter of fact, who am I? I am quite famous.

Comment: Are you using 'envelop' on purpose or should it be 'envelope'?

Comment: @SlashmanX My mistake. Editing

Comment: ...through an airplane?

Comment: @feelinferrety Sorry if this is grammatically incorrect. Please feel free to edit it if you can improve it. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you and your archenemy:

> Sherlock Holmes and Professor Moriarty?

*Did you miss me? I hope you are alright.*

> **"Did you miss me"** is what Moriarty says on every screen in the last episode of Sherlock (credit to Lord of dark)

*And your closest person. What is he doing? Does he get any patients now?*:

> **Dr.** Watson, explaining the 'patients' part

*I also hope your elder girlfriend Nerie is fine.*:

> **Irene** Adler, an anagram of 'Nerie'

*I am waiting for you at your home. And yeah, I have the key to the last part of your name.*:

> Sher**lock**, is actually pretty self-explanatory

Comment: Well, that didn't take long.

Comment: "Did you miss me" is what Moriarty says on every screen in the last episode of Sherlock

Comment: @Lordofdark Ah that explains the second line, thanks :)

Comment: @Lordofdark [Here is that scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJl5EPBa2Bw)... **Spoiler Alert**

Comment: I intended another anagram but it might not be possible now. But please add explanition about language tag.

Comment: @manshu Do you mean 'elder/eldar' as an anagram for 'Adler'. I thought about it but it didn't really work indeed :p

Comment: The language part was a long shot...So I just removed it.

Comment: @manshu Can you explain what you wanted to hear? I had a few ideas but none of them were really convincing

Comment: We discussed this matter here:http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29314381#29314381